# Is there another way to delete a device from a pioneer dmh 100bt deck

Tags: audio

I didn't hook up this light green wire to the e brake and was wondering in I can just hook it up to the ground. Or is there another way to access the setting without having to hook up the wire

[image]

[image]

[User Manual](https://www.pioneerelectronics.com/StaticFiles/Manuals/Car/DMH-100BT_OwnersManual081219.pdf)

Comment: Why don’t you just connect the wire correctly?